# C++, static члены шаблонного класса

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, static

Рассмотрим следующий код:

```
template <typename TYPE_OF_CELL>
class Map
{
    public:
    static const size_t MAX_SIZE;
};
```

Член `MAX_SIZE` обозначает максимальный размер карты.

Я хочу понять следующее:

- Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы член `MAX_SIZE` был общим для всех объектов всех типов, которые порождены данным шаблоном?

Comment: Сделайте `MAX_SIZE` просто глобальной переменной :) А вообще - в чем сверхзадача? Не XY ли это проблема?

Comment: Про глобальную переменную все понятно. Мне просто интересно, можно ли это сделать в рамках шаблона класса.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно поместить его в базовый класс:

```
class GenericMap {
public:
    static const size_t MAX_SIZE;
}

template <typename TYPE_OF_CELL>
class Map: public GenericMap {
  //...
};
```

Также можно сделать его `constexpr`. Технически общим он не станет, но на практике для константы времени компиляции разницы не будет:

```
template <typename TYPE_OF_CELL>
class Map: public GenericMap {
    constexpr static size_t MAX_SIZE=1024;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы не стал использовать память для этого:

```
template <typename TYPE_OF_CELL>
class Map
{
public:
    enum { MAX_SIZE = 1024 };
};
```

Константа  `MAX_SIZE` известна во время компиляции и  есть общая константа для всех специализаций